# Update different columns with a condition?

Tags: mysql

I have a table tbl_a, with "ID" as a primary key, with columnns "GROUP_ID","DATE","LENGTH","VALID","CID"

I'd like to make an update query that would update as:

`UPDATE all GROUP_ID` of `7` to be `CID=9`, and 
`if(DATE+LENGTH<TODAY)` // I want to say if the DATE column with the addition of LENGTH months is smaller than today's date(NOW()),

```
THEN
 SET VALID to be FALSE
for that row.
```

using YYYY-mm-dd  format

so that if the table was

```
ID| GROUP_ID | DATE       | LENGTH| VALID| CID  
---------------------------------------------------
 1|     7    | 2011-12-01 |     1 |    1 |   2 
 2|     7    | 2012-01-01 |     1 |    1 |   7 
 3|     7    | 2012-02-01 |     1 |    1 |   2 
 4|     7    | 2012-03-01 |     2 |    1 |   3
```

after the update:

```
ID| GROUP_ID | DATE       | LENGTH| VALID| CID  
---------------------------------------------------
 1|     7    | 2011-12-01 |     1 |    0 |   9 // res:2012-12-01,update VALID
 2|     7    | 2012-01-01 |     1 |    0 |   9 // res:2012-02-01,update VALID
 3|     7    | 2012-02-01 |     1 |    1 |   9 // res:2012-03-01,no update for VALID
 4|     7    | 2012-03-01 |     2 |    1 |   9 // res:2012-05-01,no update for VALID
```

Could you please tell me the syntax for that query?

Comment: The statement "UPDATE all GROUP_ID of 7 to be CID=9" is unclear.  You'll need to be clearer about what you want to happen when the condition `DATE+LENGTH<TODAY` is true.

Comment: What does `length` signify - hours, minutes, days, years?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE TableX
SET cid = 9
  , valid = CASE WHEN `date` + INTERVAL length MONTH < CURDATE()
                 THEN 0
                 ELSE valid
            END
WHERE group_id = 7
```

Comment: #ypercube, does it mean the "ELSE valid" could also be ELSE 1 or something else?

Comment: Yes, off course it could what you want. I assumed you don't want to change the column in that case.